# Illegal unquoted character for Logstash's Google Cloud Storage input plugin

Tags: logstash, google-cloud-storage, logstash-configuration

I am trying to download stackdriver logs from my GCP bucket using logstash with this configuration:

```
 google_cloud_storage {
    interval => 60
    bucket_id => "stackdriverlog\-cloudraid"
    json_key_file => "/home/boli/Documents/fullproject.json"
    file_matches => ".*json"
    codec => "json_lines"
    type=> "stackdriver1"   }
```

But it returns error message like this:

> [ERROR] 2019-05-07 17:30:57.430 [[main]-pipeline-manager] pipeline - Error registering plugin {:pipeline_id=>"main", :plugin=>"\"stackdriverlog\\-cloudraid\", json_key_file=>\"/home/boli/Documents/fullproject.json\", codec=>\"json_lines_ace8fe5a-be94-4b16-ada7-afad4cffc5d5\", enable_metric=>true, charset=>\"UTF-8\", delimiter=>\"\n\">, interval=>60, id=>\"e10c3564ee527af63666c0e5f5d00a31a8b847132776c2537f54167c4508ba8a\", type=>\"stackdriver1\", file_matches=>\".*json\", enable_metric=>true, file_exclude=>\"^$\", metadata_key=>\"x-goog-meta-ls-gcs-input\", delete=>false, unpack_gzip=>true, temp_directory=>\"/tmp/ls-in-gcs\">", :error=>"Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value\n at [Source: (FileInputStream); line: 5, column: 239]", :thread=>"#"}
>   [ERROR] 2019-05-07 17:30:58.160 [[main]-pipeline-manager] pipeline - Pipeline aborted due to error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=>com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value

I was following https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage.html#plugins-inputs-google_cloud_storage-codec for writing the configuration. Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like this is the problem:

```
"stackdriverlog\-cloudraid"
```

Why do you have a backslash in there?